# How to set picture properties using SpreadSheetLight Library - C#

Tags: c#, spreadsheetlight

Good Day,
I am using SpreadSheetLight library(https://spreadsheetlight.com/) to create new excel files. In one of the cells, I am inserting image from file. I want to **enable** picture property "Move and size with cells" but can't find any way to do it. What's happening because of this is that while the picture looks ok in the excel file, when printing, the picture is getting shrunk. Really hoping someone could help in this regard.
Below is sample code of inserting the picture. [image: How to set this property]

```
byte[] imgdata = File.ReadAllBytes(sTempSnapName);
SLPicture pic = new SLPicture(imgdata, ImagePartType.Png);

//The pic size in inches
pic.ResizeInEMU((long) SLConvert.FromInchToEmu( 3.51), (long)SLConvert.FromInchToEmu(2.71));
pic.SetPosition(27, 0);

//How to Set "Move and size with cells" option?

oMainReportXlsx.InsertPicture(pic);
```

Thanks,
Kev

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called [Picture.Placement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.picture.placement?view=excel-pia) where you can set [predefined XlPlacement value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlplacement).

However, this functionality is not supported in the .NET library **Spreadsheet Light** directly (I've checked the source code, there is no mention of  `Placement` as of now - 30.05.2023). If you want achieve such behavior, you must use other .NET library (e.g. [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia) ):

```cs
Excel.Shape myPicture = _ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Location,
                            MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                            TargetLeft,
                            TargetTop,
                            TargetWidth,
                            TargetHeight);

myPicture.Placement = Excel.XlPlacement.xlMoveAndSize;
```

Comment: many thanks @Tatrar for quick reply. The MS Excel Interop library is what I was trying to avoid. I selected SpreadhseetLight after looking at various options that were kind of free. It was all good until I came across this specific issue. I may have to do some workaround to make the images work in excel display and when printing in PDF.